# Problem with graphics after suspend on GMA500

Tags: suspend, gma500, screen-corruption, poulsbo

I have a problem with suspend on Ubuntu 12.04 running on my Dell Mini 1010 (with a GMA500 aka Poulsbo graphics card). After suspend (e.g. closing the lid), the graphics are corrupted as shown in this picture

[image]

How can this be fixed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems solved at

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/HardwareSupportComponentsVideoCardsPoulsbo/ .

Please see option 1 and 2 if issue is common or subject ***Fix suspend***.

Comment: PS BTW new kernel 3.4 works correct with out any changes